# Can we add a thousands separator to the reputation on the "This page requires more privileges" page?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, privileges, numbers

Can we add a thousands separator to the reputation in the "This page requires more privilege" page?

If we have not yet achieved the reputation to the privileges and are trying to access the tool options, we will receive the "This page requires more privileges" page. In that, the reputation doesn't have the thousands separator. Adding that, will improve the readability.

Since we have the thousands separator to the reputation on all the privilege pages.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats

> [image: 10k]

https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics

> [image: 25k]

Comment: Would you prefer a space, half-space, apostrophe, dot, comma or something else entirely as delimiter?

Comment: @mast To matching with the privileges pages, the delimiter should be comma.

Comment: Since SE is US-based, I would assume commas.  Or perhaps it could be a localization feature to use decimals if that's what your culture uses for larger numbers.

Comment: @Mast or, just reduce it like we do with rep with "k". 10k, 2.5k, or 25k.

Comment: @Script47 That would work too.